# Magento links from the sample data are broken

Tags: php, apache, magento, wamp

I installed magento using wamp. Magento cand display the homepage, but if I click on something from the home page I get `The requested URL /magento/accessories/eyewear.html was not found on this server.` I cleared the cached and I reindexed everything. I found some solutions like `RewriteBase /magento/`  or something about apache virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
<Directory /var/www/magento/>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

but I don't know how to do those things. Do you have any suggestions that might help my problem ? My httpd.conf from apache folder has

```
# Virtual hosts
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf.
```

I have no idea how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Make sure your .htaccess file still intact.

Re-copy it over from your installation files or locate one of the optimized versions online, such as this one: http://www.learnmagento.org/magento-tutorials/best-htaccess-magento/

2) If that doesn't work, then then mod_rewrite is probably disabled in your WAMP's httpd.conf file.

Within httpd.conf, find this line:

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

And change to (remove the `#`):

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Then re-start WAMP